# Autocovariance and autocorrelation functions

Tags: analysis, time-series

Let us take the following $(X_t), \; t\in Z$ process: $X_t = \epsilon t\eta t$, where $\epsilon t$ and $\eta t$
are independent processes (from each other and in time as well), $\epsilon t$ is a white noise with $0$ expectation and $\sigma$ standard deviation, $P(\eta t = 0) = P(\eta t = 2) = 1/2 \; \forall t$. Is the process $X_t$ weakly stationary? Compute the autocovariance and autocorrelation functions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a MathJax tutorial.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)